# How to Emit signals from javascript to qml

Tags: javascript, qt, qt4, qml, qt-quick

I want to emit signal from javascript-file and receive it in qml-file (To find when time-consuming operation will finished).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither Alex's nore Raja's solutions really answer the question. Alex's consists in calling directly from the javascript code the QML slot method, and Raja's consist in setting the value of a property of a QML object from the Javascript code. Both approaches negate the main advantage of the signal/slot mechanism which is that the signalling object does not need to know of the slot.

An approach closer to the spirit of the signal/slot mechanism is described in this [blog post](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/emitting-signal-from-javascript-in-qml.html) (not mine). It consists, within the javascript file, of creating a QML object (via the `Qt.createQmlObject()` function) the sole function of which is to contain the javascript's object signals. Signals are emitted from javascript through calling the internal QML objects signal (e.g. `internalQmlObject.signalName()`), and the javascript object signal can be connected in QML to QML slots with the usual `connect` mechanism via `javascriptObject.internalQmlObject.signalName.connect(receiver.slotName)`.

An example adapted from the blog post is below:

javascript_object.js:

```
var internalQmlObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.0; QtObject { signal someSignal(int value) }', Qt.application, 'InternalQmlObject');

function doSomething() {
    internalQmlObject.someSignal(42);
}
```

test.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import 'javascript_object.js' as JavascriptObject

Rectangle {

    Rectangle {
        id: someComponent

        function someSlot(v) {
            console.log("Signal received " + v);
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        JavascriptObject.internalQmlObject.someSignal.connect(someComponent.someSlot);
        JavascriptObject.doSomething();
    }
}
```

On execution it gives the following:

```
% qmlscene test.qml
Signal received 42
```

Comment: I'm agree. Good solution.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you, @RajaVarma.

I found solution for myself.

In **qml-file**: create element Item (my loginItem) which contains function that plays the role of slot.
For example (I need to know when handle login event):

```
import "scripts/auth.js" as Auth
...
Item {
   id: loginItem

   // Send himself to javascript module named Auth
   Component.onCompleted: {
      Auth.setLoginItem(loginItem);
   }

   // "Slot" function
   function logged() {
      console.debug("Login successfully");
      // Do something
      ...
   }
}
```

In **js-file**: create receiver for loginItem and use it.

```
var loginItem;

function setLoginItem(tempLoginItem) {
    loginItem = tempLoginItem;
}

...
   // Emit "signal"
   loginItem.logged();
...
```

Comment: not related to question but it is "logged in" not "logined" ;)

Comment: I'm sorry for my English. I promise to go on language course this month.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's very hacky to call signals from a real JS file. But there's a better option, IMHO, used it myself instead. Create your own class.

MyClass.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject
{
    property var myVariable
    function myFunction() { console.log("emitting signal"); mySignal() }
    signal mySignal
}
```

This way you can easily achieve the needed encapsulation. And you can even nicely connect to the object.

Then you can do whatever you want with it: create a singleton from it, create a global object, instantiate it.